# Twitter r messages cut off

Tags: r, twitter

I'm pulling tweets using TwitterR, but I'm finding that some of the tweets are cut off.

Is there any option in TwitterR to prevent for the messages to be cut off?

For example, running the following:

```
library(twitteR)
setup_twitter_oauth("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx")
searchTwitter('Los expertos dicen', n=10)
```

Note, I'm not link to this tweets. I just found them randomly.

You will see that in the tweet that there are dots end as '...'. For example:

```
"xxxx: RT @xxxx: Los expertos dicen que los osos polares podrían desaparecer en los próximos 100 años.\nFuente: Save The Ártic https://t.co/…"
```

Is it possible to get the full message using TwitterR?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually it should give you the entire tweet when you use the searchTwitter function. Can you try to save your search like this and show the results in the text to check if it is really cut off. Like:

```
Tweets<-searchTwitter('Los expertos dicen', n=10)
Tweets$text
```

To get rid of the retweets aftewards, use:

```
strip_retweets(Tweets, strip_manual = TRUE, strip_mt = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks Re Ne for your comment. I found that I need to use something like: Tweets<-searchTwitter('Los expertos dicen que los osos polares', n=10) Tweets[[10]]$text. I think the problem could be that they are reTwits. I'm not sure if it is possible to get the original Twit and if you can quantify how many reTwits have been created

Comment: I think in the twitteR library, the searchTwitter function can not control for retweets when sending a query to the API. You can try to clean afterwards using the strip_retweets function to remove retweets.

Comment: strip_retweets? Okay, I'll give it a try. Thanks